# How to define PK and FK on the same property

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I reimplementing membership propvider and want to keep original DB scheme. I have 2 classes:

```
class UserProfile
{
  public int UserId {get;set}   //PK
......
}

class Membership
{
  public int UserId {get;set;}  //FK to UserProfile.UserId
.........
}
```

Now I attaching Membership.UserId as FK to UserProfile.UserId using FluentAPI and I want it also be PK for Membership table.

I can guarantee that UserProfile.UserId is DB generated identity and will never repeated.
I tried the following code but it was failed during creating migration with error:

**Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'UserId' was already defined.**

```
HasKey(k => k.UserId);                        //Declare it as PK           !!!!
Map(m => m.ToTable("webpages_membership"));   //Setup table name

HasRequired(t => t.User)                        //Nav.property to the UserProfile
    .WithRequiredDependent(t1 => t1.Membership) //Rev.nav.property from the UserProfile
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId"));              //FK to the UserProfile    !!!!
```

If I removing any row marked by exclamation signs migration created fine but with wrong columns name.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
...
modelBuilder.Entity<Membership>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.UserId });

modelBuilder.Entity<Membership>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.User)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Membership);
```

with entities...

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key] public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Membership Membership { get; set; }
}
public class Membership
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public UserProfile User { get; set; }
}
```

...or just `.WithOptional();` if you wanna drop the Membership navigation property on the User.